# Unable to run a javascript file in CMD

Tags: javascript, node.js

i can't run a js file in cmd. please help me

```
D:\>Node
Welcome to Node.js v12.14.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
> 001.js
undefined
> Node 001.js
Thrown:
Node 001.js
     ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to mention the file name with the `node` command, like:

`node server.js`

You first need to navigate into the root directory for the file you want to run then run that command `node <fileName>`

Comment: i do it but this error :> Node 001.js
Thrown:
Node 001.js
     ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Answer (score -1):

You need to navigate into the root directory for the file you want to run then run hit :

```
node filename.js
```

You can install package called nodemon to restart the file every time you do a change on it.the following installation code :

```
npm i nodemon
```

Then hit :

```
nodemon filename.js
```